# Change androidmanifest.xml file to Binary xml file

Tags: android, xml-parsing, binary, apk, reverse-engineering

I am able to unpack an android apk file with **apktool**, but when I am repacking the apk file using apktool, it just crashes with errors, and [ibotpeaches](https://ibotpeaches.github.io/) seems not patching those errors for years. now come into my question, could you please help me to recompile that androidmanifest.xml to a binary xml using any other tool or techniques.

Comment: Is this a request of professional service?

Comment: @AlexCohn yes, you can say that.

Comment: You can contact me on LinkedIn or Skype.